# Multiple NUnit Test Classes fail when trying to access an image resource from a Resource Dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, nunit

I have a complex WPF project written in C# (.NET 4.0) which I wrote a couple of tests for (NUnit). Theses tests reside in different classes and as long as I run the tests for each class individually everything is fine. However, once I try to run all tests of all classes at once the tests of the first class succeed, but once the testrunner (Resharper or nunit-console) starts testing the remaining classes, all of them fail with the following stack trace.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.VerifyAccess()
at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.ToString()
at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrameDecode.ConvertToString(String format, IFormatProvider provider)
at System.Windows.Media.ImageSource.ToString()
at MUSTANG.ShowCase.ResourceLibrary.ResourceDictionaryManager.GetUriString(String pKey) in c:\Daten\Jenkins-ci\jobs\MUSTANG-Showcase-Release-VS2010\workspace\MUSTANG-Showcase\MUSTANG.ShowCase.ResourceLibrary\ResourceDictionaryManager.cs:Zeile 49.
```

The corresponding code is the following:

```
public object GetValue(string pKey)
{
    if (mDictionary.Contains(pKey))
    {
        return mDictionary[pKey];
    }
    return null;
}

public String GetUriString(string pKey)
{
    object result = GetValue(pKey);
    if (null == result)
    {
        Log.Warn(string.Format(@"Ressource '{0}' nicht gefunden!", pKey));
        return "";
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

The exception occurs on the last line in GetUriString when the resource was an image. Nunit seems to use different threads to run the different test classes - still they are run in sequence. Is there any way to resolve this problem e.g. by either telling NUnit or the testrunners to use a single thread, to completely quit after each test class run or similar?

Edit 1: What I have tried so far:

- Decorating tests with `[RequiresSTA]` attribute
- Before running each test class reseting the ResourceDictionaryManager class (which is where this error occurs). This solved the problem in the ResourceDictionaryManager class but then the exact same problem occurs "later" in code.
- Copying all tests into the same gigantic class. All tests run fine (but that's not what I want)

The problem seems to be that NUnit uses a different thread for each class that contains test methods, so I either need to find a way to

- tell NUnit to run all test classes in the same thread

OR

- tell NUnit in the TestFixtureTearDown method to completely shutdown the application so I can instantiate a new application in the next test class using `new Application();`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the stacktrace, you posted it appears that you have a 'thread affinity' problem - i.e. you are trying to update a UI element on a thread different from the one that it was created on.
BitmapDecoder is derived from DispatcherObject i.e. it needs to operate on a single thread. It seems in your test run, it is being created on one thread and then method calls (ToString) are being made from a different thread.

- Are you positive that you are not spawning threads in your code ? NUnit AFAIK uses the same thread to run all tests within a test-run. What version are you running?
- Are you sharing the same instance of `MUSTANG.ShowCase.ResourceLibrary` across tests? How about creating a new instance for each test i.e isolating tests ?

**Update:** I think I have it nailed down now.

- If the test fixture is marked just with the TestFixture attribute, (No threading requirements), all tests are run on a single MTA thread
- If you mark each TestFixture with the RequiresSTA attribute, I see that the runner will create a new STA thread for each test fixture (which seems to match what you're reporting).
- Since you want all your tests (across fixtures) on the same STA thread, you should specify this at the assembly level (in the AssemblyInfo.cs file). You can drop the attribute at every fixture level.

.

```
[assembly: RequiresThread(ApartmentState.STA)]
```

Comment: Hello, when I run the test with nunit-console I'm running Nunit 2.6, resharpers test runner uses NUnit 2.5.10. As long as I run tests only on a single class all tests are run from the same thread (and so succeed). But as soon as the testrunner switches to the second test class for some reason it creates a new thread and so all tests of the second test class fail.

Comment: About your second point: I will investigate this. Currently the class is implemented as a singleton, but maybe I have to change that. I would also like to completely kill the application between each test, but am not sure how to do that. I use `new Application()`in my SetupFixture since WPF depends on Àpplication.Current` and so do my tests but I guess this also will cause some problems.

Comment: OK, I added to my SetUpFixture methods to reset the ResourceDictionary before the testrunner runs a new test class. Now a lot of tests succeed, but still a lot of tests fail with the same exception but on another place. It seems there are a lot places I have to reset, in order to get the tests running, so this is probably not the solution.

Comment: I meant `[TestFixtureSetup]` instead of SetUpFixture in above comment. Just to be clear.

Comment: @David - just checked with nunit v2.6.2 on .net 4.5, NUnit GUI runner does not spawn multiple threads across tests/test classes. So the multiple threads seem to be coming from the production code.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure it is coming from NUnit (I'm actually using the nunit-console-x86.exe) since this problem does only occur, when the tests remain in different test classes (besides these tests cover base functionalities, we would for sure have noticed, if those threads would be spawned from our code). Maybe NUnit GUI runner behaves different from the nunit-console application, I can not tell right now

Comment: @David - Can you log the stacktrace and the threadID at 2 places, where the Object with thread affinity is being created AND when it is being exercised (the place where the exception happens).. that should shed some light on the origin of the 2 threads in question.

Comment: I uploaded a log to http://pastebin.com/7YMKvzxF it contains a test run of 4 different tests, the first two (DimensionsRemoveNullTest and DimensionsRemoveTest) were from the first test class, the second two (MeasuresAddNullTest and MeasuresAddTest) from the second. The first two tests were run from thread with ID 8 (as you can see the ResourceDictionaryManager is initialized from this thread), the other two tests are run from thread ID 13 (therefore these two are seen in the log when the exception occurs). Still I'm not sure how I can identify who spawned the new thread...

Comment: @David - Check out the update to my answer and let me know if that worked.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I solved it now by running the tests via NUnit console with the `/runlist` parameter (e.g. `C:\NUnit-2.6.0.12051\bin\nunit-console-x86.exe My.Assembly.dll /xml=result.xml /runlist=..\testlist.txt`) where `testlist.txt` contains the fully qualified names of all my test classes. This way NUnit seems to completely restart the whole application for each class to be tested. Drawback of this method is, that I have to add to this list, once I add a new test class but for now, this solution is fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `RequiresSTA` attribute to the test fixture. See here: http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=requiresSTA&r=2.5.9

There's also `RequiresThread` and `RequiresMTA` (Multi thread) attributes, linked from the same article. It may not fix your issue but sounds like it should.

Comment: I already have decorated my testclasses with the `[RequiresSTA]` attribute but thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make sure you `Freeze` all `ImageSource` objects in the `ResourceDictionary`. If a `Freezable` (such as `ImageSource`) is frozen, then it can be accessed from multiple threads, but is unmodifiable.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I modified my function to cast the resource to a Freezable and call the Freeze method, but the exact same error still persists when calling the resource.ToString() method

Comment: OK. Another option might be to capture the current `Dispatcher` instance when the `ResourceDictionaryManager` is created and then use `Invoke` whenever you need to call `GetUriString` for an `ImageSource`.

Comment: Thanks again. As I just stated in my above comment, ResourceDictionaryManager seems not to be the only place where the problem of accessing objects from a different thread occurs (but the first) so calling the dispatcher will for sure solve the problem of accessing different image resources (hence not tested) but the problem then occurs on lots of different places "later" in code. So unfortunately this is not the way to go (for me).